# Where to put the using declaration

Tags: c++

What's the recommended practice regarding the `using` declaration (e.g `using std::vector;`)?

Should it be at the top of the cpp/cc file or just in the scope where it's being used?

Comment: `using` shouldn't be used at all except for ADL control and unhiding base names. If a namespace name is too long, use a namespace alias.

Comment: see here, for an explanation of what kerrek said: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/893693

Comment: @MikMik: Just a case, where it when wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9279462/1141095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability its better to have it at the beginning. 
Otherwise, use it in the smallest scope possible.

To make the code clearer to other, you should avoid using `using`.

**update**:

Please take mezhaka's comment into account. I wasn't precise enough, but referred with "at the beginning" to the beginning of the "real" code, i.e. after the `#includes`'s

Comment: If you put it in the very beginning, before the #include statements, you would affect the #included files and thus you would change the meaning of the #included code. This might be not what you wanted.

Comment: @mezhaka: Sorry for being unprecise. You are completely right. I referred more to the beginning of the "real" code.

Answer (score 2):

Limiting its scope would be better in general, but it would take a non-trivial amount of code in your source file to make a difference in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 59 of C++ Coding Standards by Sutter and Alexandrescu is named "Don't write namespace usings in a header file or before #include". So they say that you should not write using declaration or using directive before an #include directive, because this may influence the #included code. This also implies that you should not write using in your own header files, cause someone may #include them and this would alter the behavior in the inclusion point (see e.g. some Boost header library).

So don't write using in header files and before #include directive. Feel free to write using  in your implementation files after #including directives.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, because I was asking myself about the viabiliy of a piece of code making using below each #include. Like if he was doing an import in java.

Comment: Regarding `using` and headers: avoid even if it's a `using` declaration for a type (not a whole namespace) inside your own namespace to avoid lots of `std::` prefixes?

Comment: @thomthom I do not know. They only mention statements like using namespace blah; I guess using blah::type is fine. But I would love to hear from you if you find any confirmation.

Comment: I found one topic that was briefly mentioning it, but it argued name conflicts if you `using std::vector` and "someone else" defined a `vector` class in your own namespace. However, I don't see how that is any different from if I had defined a custom `Foo` class and "someone else` also tried to define a `Foo` class within my namespace. Will check back if I get more clarifying details on this particular usage. (Though, since it's hard to find it indicated few use it - but I'd still like to know *why*)

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a cpp file it is a matter of style. Some people have a preference to avoid `using` declarations all together to avoid any ambiguity. If in a header, always have it in at least some scope, otherwise stick to the rule for variables: Always try to have things in the smallest scope as possible.