# Why does cout prevent subsequent code from running here?

Tags: c++, string, cout

I'm working on a rudimentary shell, but in the loop below, the program doesn't run past the marked line (it immediately loops instead). When I comment it out, the entire block completes before looping again. What's going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  string input;
  const char *EOF="exit";
  string prompt=getenv("USER");
  prompt.append("@ash>");                                                                              

  while(true) {
    int parent=fork();
    if ( !parent ) {
      cout << prompt; //The program never gets past this point
      getline(cin,input);
      if (!input.compare(EOF))
        exit(0);
      cout << input << '\n';                                                                            
      execlp("ls", "-l", NULL);
      return 0;
    }
    else
      wait();
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be tagged c++ not c.

Comment: Do you need to flush the line with a << endl ?

Comment: How do you know that is never gets past the point you marked? Since your are missing to flush the buffer, it shouldn't be written immediately.

Comment: Richard, can you tell me quickly about your environment?

FreudianSlip, it persists with the << endl

Comment: ezdazuzena, it prints out the string infinitely and doesn't appear to be taking input. **edit:** I should have been clearer. It's obviously getting _past_ this point, because it repeats the loop, but it's not running the rest of the code in the block.

Comment: @user1209326 have you given any input?

Comment: Luchian, the input should come from cin immediately after the line in question. When I comment out cout, it takes input fine

Comment: The `wait()` doesn't wait, so the parent thread forks children in a loop and each prints out the prompt.

Comment: @Hersha: Why. He may be using some C++ constructs but all the important interfaces that are being used are C. (And simply using a few C++ objects does not really make the code C++ (this is C with a few classes thrown in)) It would definitely be worth tagging this as C and C++ as you will get the people that know about these interfaces looking at the code.

Comment: @FreudianSlip The output of the prompt should be flushed automatically with `getline`; `cin` and `cout` are tied.

Comment: And the code you post shouldn't compile (and probably won't with most compilers).  `EOF` is required to be a macro, and including `<iostream>` is required (very indirectly) to pull in its definition.

Comment: James, "EOF" is not actually EOF, but instead "const char *EOF="exit";" All is well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add these `#include`s:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

then invoke [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) correctly:

```
int status;
wait(&status);
```

Your code, `wait()`, doesn't invoke the `wait(2)` system call. Rather, it declares a temporary object of type `union wait`. If you `#include` `stdlib.h` but not `sys/wait.h`, then you only get the type declaration, not the function declaration.

By the way, if you had checked the return value of the `wait` call: `int result = wait()`, you would have received an informative error message:

> xsh.cc:26: error: cannot convert ‘wait’ to ‘int’ in initialization

Comment: Are you referring to the wait outside of the loop? What's the disadvantage of the way coded right now (legitimately curious, this was always how our instructor showed us)

Comment: **EDIT:** just saw your edit. I must have just been crazy then. Thank you!

Comment: My edit is technically incorrect. The conflicting symbol is not from `std::wait`, it is `union wait` which is provided in `stdlib.h`. I will update my edit.